# I got ActivityNotFoundException error when i was trying to startup a new activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I am trying to start an activity that setup an email account from my main activity. Its not working and driving me nuts. What I have is:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            ComponentName cname = new ComponentName("com.android.email",
            "com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics");
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.username", username.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.password", password.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.extra.eas_flow", true);
            intent.setComponent(cname);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Manifest is:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And I always get this error:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.email/com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I'm new to this, who can tell me how to solve this error?

Any response is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a package installed on your device named com.android.email, and declaring AccountSetupBasics activity in its manifest?

Comment: thx for your reply, but i ran this on eclipse's AVD, how can i check if this package is installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can only start other's activity if it is exported. Check if `com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics` is. And you should always do `try/catch` as `startActivity()` can throw exception for more reasons and if you will let it go uncaught, your app will crash

Comment: Should i import some jar file which includes com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics? I can't find this under my project

Comment: No. There're no "some jars" to solve all you problems. If activity is not exported then you do nothing with it.

Comment: Could you clarify more about activity is not exported?

Comment: Do you mean that i need to define this activity in manifest file?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported

Comment: It's not your activity. You can't do much if original app is not letting you use that activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            ComponentName cname = new ComponentName("com.android.email",
            "com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics");
            Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, targetActvity.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.username", username.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.password", password.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.extra.eas_flow", true);
            intent.setComponent(cname);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: targetActvity is AccountSetupBasics, but the project can't resolve this, could you tell me which jar file i need to import?

Comment: This answer would work if the target Activity was indeed in the same package. It does not seem to be the case here!